# How to work with protected model attributes--foreign keys (mass-assignment protection error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys, protected, attr-accessible

In my application I have a *course* model that *belongs to* three other models: user, subject, and student_level (they include *has many* in model descriptions).

To be able to create a course, I declared foreign keys for two models in *course* model as attr_accessible.

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :objectives, :title, :subject_id, :student_level_id


  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :subject
  belongs_to :student_level
```

This is my _fields.html.slim file for creating a course:

```
= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object

= f.label :title, t("activerecord.attributes.course.title")
= f.text_field :title

= f.label :subject_id, t("activerecord.attributes.subject.title")
= f.collection_select(:subject_id, Subject.all, :id, :title_for_select)

= f.label :student_level_id, t("activerecord.attributes.student_level.title")
= f.collection_select(:student_level_id, StudentLevel.all, :id, :title_for_select)

= f.label :objectives, t("activerecord.attributes.course.objectives")
= f.text_area :objectives, rows: 15, cols: 10
```

And this is my new method in courses_controller.rb

```
 #GET /courses/new
  def new
    @course = current_user.courses.new
    # @subjects = Subject.all
    # @student_levels = StudentLevel.all
  end
```

Above code shows that I am mass-assigning *subject* and *student level* attributes.

What is bothering me, is that in Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial for version 3.2 (for example, p. 536, listing 10.7) these foreign keys should be protected. And there is an example for protected foreign key assignment.

Right now everything works fine. Also, my config/application.rb contains
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

Right now if I remove subject_id and student_level_id from attr_accessible (so they become protected), the application gives

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in CoursesController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: subject_id, student_level_id
```

My question: what is the best practice when creating an entity with two foreign keys, is there a way to create/edit without exposing foreign keys as attr_accessible for mass-assignment?

Thank you very much!

UPDATE:

```
  #POST /courses/
  def create
    @course = current_user.courses.new(params[:course])
    if @course.save
      flash[:success] = t("messages.course_created")
      redirect_to @course
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you plz paste the code of create action ?

Comment: @AmitThawait I updated my question -- added create method at the end. I couldn't reply to your comment.

Comment: No problem, I hope you understood my point. Thanks... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the code of your course form `my _fields.html.slim`, it looks like you are taking `subject_id, student_level_id` from user only through `select box`, so they should be accessible.

What should be protected is : say for example, you have `Institue` model and `course` belongs to an `Institue` and you have a `foreign_key` as `institute_id`, then this `institute_id` should be protected.

Other Example which I can give you is, say

`Project` belongs_to `User` and `User` has many `projects`

and you have a foreign key `user_id` in `projects` table :

then while creating a project you should do something like :

```
#This will create a new project object with user_id set as id of current_user
current_user.projects.new
```

Now to create a project object with params :

```
current_user.projects.new(params[:project])
```

I am not sure that, their is any way to create a object with two protected attributes but definitely in your case the attributes `subject_id, student_level_id` should not be protected.